# How to select words that are made up of the same letter using regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a dictionary text file that contains some words that I don't want.

Example:

```
aa
aaa
aaaa
bb
b
bbb
```

etc

I want to use a regular expression to select these words and remove them. However,
what I have seems to be getting too long and there must be a more efficient approach.

Here is my code so far:

```
/^a{1,6}$|^b{1,6}$|^c{1,6}$|^d{1,6}$|^e{1,6}$|^f{1,6}$|^g{1,6}$|^[i]{2,3}$/
```

It seems that I have to do this for every letter.  How could I do this more succinctly?

Comment: Even if you did this for every letter, what about `ñññññ`?

Comment: What kind of dictionary is that?

Comment: The dictionary is just a list of words that are supposed to exist in the English language.  They include abbreviations etc which I want to remove.

Comment: This dictionary does not contain the ñ as its not in English.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is down voted. I'm learning regex and reaching out for help with a clear question that has attracted some great feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this regex:

```
\b([a-z])\1{0,}\b
```

and replace by empty

Ruby code sample:

```
re = /\b([a-z])\1{0,}\b/m
str = 'aa aaa aaaa bb b bbb abc aa a pqaaa '
result = str.gsub(re,'')
puts result
```

[Run the code here](http://ideone.com/EqpzbH)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I chose this one as it was easier for me to understand and fit into my existing code.

Comment: One more request. I don't want to remove the word 'I'. How can I have an exception for the single letter 'I'?

Answer (score 3):

It's a lot easier to collapse the word down to unique letters and remove all of those with just one letter in them:

```
words = "aa aaa aaaa bb b bbb etc aab abcabc"

words.split(/\s+/).select do |word|
  word.chars.uniq.length > 1
end
# => ["etc", "aab", "abcabc"]
```

This splits your string into words, then selects only those words that have more than one type of character in them (`.chars.uniq`)

Comment: Yes. To quote famous Jamie Zawinski: 

*"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.*

While regular expressions are powerful, they tend to become write-only, and it is hard to make them match exactly (no less, no more) what you want.

Comment: That is a very interesting idea.  The file is pretty big though about 5mb. Just wondering if it would be faster to do this or use a regex.

Comment: @chell sounds like you are doing this over and over again. Wouldn't it be easier to remove the unwanted words once and save a new (clean) file that you can use instead?

Comment: @chell This does use a (tiny) regular expression to split things. Not everything is faster as a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

^([a-z])\1?\1?\1?\1?\1?$

Match any single letter, followed by 5 optional backreferences to the initial letter.

This might work too:

^([a-z])\1{,5}$

Comment: That's a really weak regular expression. That it has to be customized for each length is not very good.

Comment: The question had the same limitation.  It was not clear that limitation wasn't desired.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
\b([a-zA-Z])\1*\b
```

if you want (in addition to letters) to include also repeated digits or underscores, use this code:

```
\b([\w])\1*\b
```

**Update:**

To exclude `I` from being removed:

```
(?i)ii+|\b((?i)[a-hj-z])\1*\b
```

`(?i)` is added above to make letters not case sensitive.

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/gFUWE8/7

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim will use it.  I still want to the regex to match ii and iii as the dictionary has those in it too though.